# Accessing Googles Palm api from Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch, palm-api, makersuite

There are currently a few QuickStart's for Palm API text.

[PaLM API: Text Quickstart](https://developers.generativeai.google/tutorials/text_quickstart)

The examples show how to do this in Python, but I have not found any way of getting it to work with Google Apps Script.

Can I send a request to this API with Apps Script directly, or do I need to wait for them to create a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find any direct information about the endpoint to call but [Makersuite](https://developers.googleblog.com/2023/03/announcing-palm-api-and-makersuite.html) gave me a curl example which I was then able to figure out what the call looked like

[image]

```
curl \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -X POST 'https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta2/models/text-bison-001:generateText?key='${API_KEY} \
  -d '{ "prompt": { "text": "Write a poem about an adventure in an underwater castle\n\n"}, "temperature": 0.7, "top_k": 40, "top_p": 0.95, "candidate_count": 1, "max_output_tokens": 1024, "stop_sequences": [], "safety_settings": [{"category":"HARM_CATEGORY_DEROGATORY","threshold":1},{"category":"HARM_CATEGORY_TOXICITY","threshold":1},{"category":"HARM_CATEGORY_VIOLENCE","threshold":2},{"category":"HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUAL","threshold":2},{"category":"HARM_CATEGORY_MEDICAL","threshold":2},{"category":"HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS","threshold":2}]}'
```

Then I was able to use UrlFetchApp.fetch to access the data from the PALM api directly via app script.  This seems to work well until they create a library for it.

```
function myFunction() {
  
  // Make a POST request with form data.
  var data = {
              "prompt": {
                    "text": "Write a story about a magic backpack."
                    },
              "temperature": 1.0,
              "candidateCount": 2};
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };


  try {
      
      const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta2/models/text-bison-001:generateText?key=REDACTED', options);
      Logger.log(response);
      const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

      Logger.log(data.candidates[0].output);
  } catch (f) {
      Logger.log(f.message);
  }
}
```

The tricky part was parsing the response. It returns in an array sometimes there can be more then one candidate.

Comment: Makersuite Link is not public